# How to use variable in the array name

Tags: vue.js, v-for

I am building a calendar view of assigned tasks, with an array controlling which tasks should display in each day's cell.  I need to reference a varying array key in the v-for loop, but can't find the proper syntax.

My dataset (for tasks on the 5th and 6th of the month) is:

```
assignments: {
   '05':
       [
         'task one',
         'task two'
       ],
   '06':
       [
         'task three',
         'task four'
       ]
},
```

This hard-coding to day ['05'] works as I'd like:

```
<tbody id="calendar-table">
   <tr>
       <td v-for="(day, index) in calendar.days_array" v-if="index < 7">
           <table>
               <tr>
                   {{day}}
               </tr>
               <tr v-for="task_name in condensedAssignments['05']">
                   <td>
                        {{task_name}}
                   </td>
               </tr>
           </table>
      </td>
   </tr>
```

This gets the attached screenshot:
[calendar with tasks within all days](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pqdYJ.png)

I want to replace the '05' in the second loop with the contents of the variable "day" of the first loop.  Variations on **v-for="task_name in assignments[{{day}}]"** are rejected.  I've looked into computed properties or methods, but haven't found a way to pass the current iteration's "day" into them.

How do I get the inner loop to recognize the "day" of the outer loop?

Comment: What does "rejected" means? Please, stick to common terms. It's unknown what days_array is. If `day` is anything but `05` and `06` *strings*, this is a mistake

Answer (score 0):

You can use the variable name as index for your `condensedAssignments` variable, but, I think it can't work because the index is a string and the variable `day` is a number.

You can do this:

```
<tr v-for="task_name in condensedAssignments[String(day).padStart(1, '0')]">
    <td>{{task_name}}</td>
</tr>
```

String(day) -> Cast variable to a string
.padStart(2, '0') -> Add one zero at left because your index is '05' then two chars long

Answer (score 0):

Actually, you have several problems here.

First, you should not use `v-if` and `v-for` on the same element. If you only want the first n elements, a solution could be to use the `slice` method : `calendar.days_array.slice(0, 7)`

The second anomaly is that your `assignments` variable isn't an Array but an Object. You can search how to iterate through an object or check this [Digital Ocean tutorial](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/vuejs-iterating-v-for).

Also, you can call the second v-for statement on your variable instead of harcoding your taskname.

It may looks something like this :

```html
<td v-for="(day, key, i) in calendar.days_array">
  <tr>{{ key }}</tr>
  <tr v-for="task_name in day">
    {{ task_name }}
  </tr>
</td>
```

Answer (score 0):

Thank you to fdisotto for the quick answer.  I tried again using a method in the meantime, and was reminded that I have another issue: My "day" field is sometimes null.  I was able to get it working, though, with this method:

```
daysTasks: function(day){
   if (!day) {return []};
   if (String(day).length < 2) {
       day = '0'+day;
   }
   return this.assignments[day];
},
```

and this template:

```
<td v-for="(day, index) in calendar.days_array" :key='day' v-if="index < 7">
    <table>
       <tr>
          {{day}}
       </tr>
       <tr v-for="task_name in daysTasks(day)" :key='task_name'>
           <td>{{task_name}}
           </td>
       </tr>
```

Now, only the 5th of the month sees the first two tasks, and the 6th sees the last two.